# How do I call a function on button click inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that displays a product and a counter to select the # of items. There are up and down buttons to increase or decrease the quantity. Here is the modal:

```
<div id="productDetailModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productDetailModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div id="productDetailDialog" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="counter" class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
        <input id="qty" value="0" />
        <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button>
      </div>
```

And here is the script function:

```
function modify_qty(val) {
  var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var new_qty = parseInt(qty, 10) + val;

  if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
  }
  console.log("Inside script.js function. new_qty= " + new_qty);
  document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
  return new_qty;
}
```

The counter works fine if I take the `#counter` `div` and place it in the body of the html page. It's only in the modal, where it doesn't work. I  output to console in the function, and it seems the function isn't getting called inside the modal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you propovide CDN URL for bootstrap you're using

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing how/where you include the javascript, but if you make sure it's in scope (check your console logs for errors), it should work.

Here's a working example:
[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/n41hLmb4/)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productDetailModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="productDetailModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="productDetailModal" aria-hidden="true">
<script>
function modify_qty(val) {
  var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
  var new_qty = parseInt(qty, 10) + val;

  if (new_qty < 0) {
    new_qty = 0;
  }
  console.log("Inside script.js function. new_qty= " + new_qty);
  document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
  return new_qty;
}
</script>
  <div id="productDetailDialog" class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div id="counter" class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="qty"><abbr title="Quantity">Qty</abbr></label>
        <input id="qty" value="0" />
        <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```